# is there a method to group same elements in the liste according to labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, nlp

i have data like :

```
data = [[234,"balablablabla"],[254,"ababaabbla"],[274,"nnnnnnnnnnblabla"],[284,"cccccccccblabla"]]
```

and i have a list of labels :

```
labels=[0,0,1,0]
```

i want to have in output: put the id of data that have the same label in  the same list, the [234,254,284] in the sam list because the labels of [234,"balablablabla"] and [254,"ababaabbla"] and [284,"cccccccccblabla"] is 0 and [274,"nnnnnnnnnnblabla"] of label 1 :

```
results =  [[234,254,284],[274]]
```

PS: the labels is of 0 or 1 in this short example but it can be 0,1,2,...,1000

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [[234,"balablablabla"],[254,"ababaabbla"],[274,"nnnnnnnnnnblabla"],[284,"cccccccccblabla"]]
labels=[0,0,1,0]
result=[[] for i in range(max(labels)-min(labels)+1)]
for i in range(len(labels)):
    result[labels[i]].append(data[i][0])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic solution would be to use a `defaultdict`. This will give you the labels as the dictionary keys and the list of labels as the corresponding values.

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = [[234, "balablablabla"], 
            [254, "ababaabbla"],
            [274, "nnnnnnnnnnblabla"],
            [284, "cccccccccblabla"]]
>>> labels = [0, 0, 1, 0]
>>> results = defaultdict(list)
>>> for label, row in zip(labels, data):
...     results[label].append(row[0])
...
>>> print(results)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [234, 254, 284], 1: [274]})
```

Now suppose there are duplicates and you want unique data against each label, then you can use a `defaultdict(set)` object instead.

```py
>>> data = [[234, "balablablabla"], 
            [254, "ababaabbla"],
            [234, "balablablabla"], # Duplicate Value
            [274, "nnnnnnnnnnblabla"], 
            [284, "cccccccccblabla"]]
>>> labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
>>> results = defaultdict(set)
>>> for label, row in zip(labels, data):
...     results[label].add(row[0])
...
>>> print(results)
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {0: {234, 284, 254}, 1: {274}})
```